# Passing data from array to amchart radar chart series

Tags: javascript, amcharts, radar-chart, amcharts4

I would like to pass the data from a data table I am added to array but I cannot see how to apply that. I have looked through the documentation to do this but to no avail.
[image]

Here is the code:

```js
/* START AMCHART CODE*/ 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* Set themes */
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_dark);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

/* Create chart instance */
var chart = am4core.create("js_chart", am4charts.RadarChart);

/* Add data */
chart.data = [{
  "region": "National",
  "value1": 501,
  "value2": 250,
  "value3": 250

}, {
  "region": "Region",
  "value1": 301,
  "value2": 222,
  "value3": 250
}, {
  "region": "PJ Lowrie",
  "value1": 266,
  "value2": 179,
  "value3": 250
}, {
  "region": "Tameside",
  "value1": 165,
  "value2": 298,
  "value3": 250
}, {
  "region": "Salford",
  "value1": 139,
  "value2": 299,
  "value3": 250
}, {
  "region": "Manchester",
  "value1": 336,
  "value2": 185,
  "value3": 250
}];

/* Read data from chartdata */
console.log(chartdata);

var chartData2 = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < chartdata.length; i++) {
    var category= new Object();
    category.category=chartdata[i].items[0];
    category.Done=chartdata[i].items[1];
    category.Begun=chartdata[i].items[2];
    category.None=chartdata[i].items[3];
    chartData2.push(category);  
}
/* End Read data from chartdata */
//chart.data =chartData2;

/* Create axes */
chart.dataProvider=chartData2;
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "region";

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 1000; 

/* Create and configure series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "value1";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "region";
series1.name = "None";
series1.strokeWidth = 0;
series1.columns.template.tooltipText = "Series: {name}\nCategory: {categoryX}\nValue: {valueY}";
series1.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series1.sequencedInterpolationDelay = 100;
series1.stacked = true;
series1.fill = "red";

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "value2";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "region";
series2.name = "Begun";
series2.strokeWidth = 0;
series2.columns.template.tooltipText = "Series: {name}\nCategory: {categoryX}\nValue: {valueY}";
series2.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series2.sequencedInterpolationDelay = 100;
series2.stacked = true;
series2.fill = "gold";

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "value3";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "region";
series3.name = "Done";
series3.strokeWidth = 0;
series3.columns.template.tooltipText = "Series: {name}\nCategory: {categoryX}\nValue: {valueY}";
series3.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series3.sequencedInterpolationDelay = 100;
series3.stacked = true;
series3.fill = "green";

/* Add legend */
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

/* Add cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.RadarCursor();

    /*END AMCHART CODE*/
```

I have a radar chart that works perfectly using the hard coded data but I would like to pass the data from the array.
Thanks
J

Comment: Have you looked through the documentation to see how to do this? 

Comment: hah It wouldn't let me post as said had too much code ;)

Comment: Remove repeated sentences and enable syntax highlighting for code block

Comment: @JayW It's very likely that there's something wrong with the format of the data  you're trying to pass in. Note that AmCharts expects an array of objects where the properties line up with the fields you define in your series, which can be seen in every demo on the site. If your data doesn't look like the hard coded data, then that's the first thing you should look at. Can you post what your data looks like?

Comment: Thanks. :)  I was guessing it was maybe that. Let me see if I can resolve that. If not I will post.

Comment: Added the screenshot of the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for responses. I have worked it out for myself via this demo and apply some other logic
amcharts.com/demos/line-graph/

```
/* Read data from chartdata */

var chartData2 = [];
var region=0;
var Done=0;
var None ='';
    for (var i = 0; i < chartdata.length; i++) {
    region=chartdata[i].items[0];
    Done=chartdata[i].items[1];
    Begun=chartdata[i].items[2];
    None=chartdata[i].items[3];
    chartData2.push({region:region, Done: Done, Begun: Begun, None: None}); 
}

chart.data = chartData2;`
```